# How do I login to SQL Server via group membership in another domain

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When attempting to connect to SQL Server (2012), I get a login failed error message. The error log on the server reports:

```
Logon        Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 5.
Logon        Login failed for user 'MYDOMAIN\mswart'. Reason: Could not find a login matching the name provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.---.--]
```

However, I expected to be able to login based on my membership to a group MYDOMAIN\MYTEAM

I'm able to login when MYDOMAIN\mswart is created as a login.

The SQL Server machine has joined domain OTHERDOMAIN and the SQL Server service account is also a member of OTHERDOMAIN.

Maybe I'm not looking at the right thing. I'm looking for troubleshooting steps I can take to narrow down the issue so I can understand why I can't log in.

Aaron Bertrand's post [Troubleshooting Error 18456](https://sqlblog.org/2011/01/14/troubleshooting-error-18456) was almost useful... in the comments, it looks like a Gary Mazzone experienced the same issue.

Comment: Do you have cross-domain trusts set up?  Are you remoting (RDP) into the OTHERDOMAIN server to make your connection?  Or can you begin the connection from a MYDOMAIN desktop?

Comment: Cross-domain trusts were set up properly

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was able to narrow down my trouble by working with my sysadmin about how the group was defined.

Knowing that the SQL Server was hosted on a machine that had joined another domain and was running with a user account on that other domain, we looked at the [Group Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692(v=ws.10).aspx) in active directory.

My user could authenticate properly after the scope was changed to universal.

If I find an authoritative source on SQL Server's behavior with respect to these domain group types, I'll be sure to update this answer.

Comment: Not authoritative but [some additional info](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5890174/847990)